# SVN commit is ALL or NONE?

Tags: svn

I am trying to delete a branch by using *svn rm local* and then *commit*. During the *commit*, I was at the top level of the project. so the *commit* command was also trying to commit other changes on other branches **which is not what I want**. fortunately, the commit failed in the middle. but some of the other changes were sent to the repository. My question is does this mean no change was actually applied to the repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> SVN commit is ALL or NONE?

Yes, it is all or none. This is called [atomicity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomicity_(database_systems)).

Subversion commits are atomic and consistent. The case you describe is not possible in Subversion by design. The commit is either successful or not. Even if your transaction was committed and resulted in creation of a new revision, you can always roll back to the previous revision.

> My question is does this mean no change was actually applied to the
>   repository?

Yes, if the commit failed in the middle (e.g. due to network problems) or was canceled by a user then there is no new revision in the repository.

> I am trying to delete a branch by using svn rm local and then commit.
>   During the commit, I was at the top level of the project.

1. Remove a branch by passing a URL, that's much easier and helps you avoid committing irrelevant changes. E.g. the command should be as follows:

   `svn delete https://svn.example.com/repos/MyRepo/branches/MyBranch -m LogMessage`
2. Checking out a working copy from repository's root can be considered as unusual practice and it appears that it is your case. You working copy should represent a project's, trunk, branch, tag or shelve. You can always switch your working copy to another development line. Moreover, you can have as many working copies on your workstation as you need or want.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have another question. you mentioned removing by passing a URL. I thought to remove local and then commit is better than that option. we have a .svn folder in the local workspace. I found that that folder is very big sometimes. I guess some version/history information is stored there. If we delete the repository copy with URL and then manually delete the local copy without using svn command, I am afraid that the related .svn folder does get cleaned. Am I worry too much?

Comment: Yes, you worry too much. Delete via the URL, then `svn update` your working copy. BTW,  read the last paragraph of this section https://subversion.apache.org/quick-start#checking-out-a-working-copy Normally you don't need a working copy with all your branches, tags etc.

Comment: In my this case, I should issue the "svn commit" command with the deleted branch path to avoid other changes being commit as well?   In the URL option, where should I issue the "svn update", under the delete target folder or add the path to point to the target location? We have several branches, I only use 4 of them. I am worrying get/update what I don't want to and committed what I don't intend to.

Comment: If you use only four branches, then checkout a working copy per branch. ‘svn delete URL’ results in immediate commit, no need do a separate commit. Note that if you remove a branch in the repository it will affect other collaborators, too. ‘svn update’ updates your working copy with new changes incoming from the repository, it does not accept URLs. Please read https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/tour/cycle/